# What should be the table contain updated row for update trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

A while ago i read the article for Trigger in SQL Server, and it said that i can use the Logical Table "Updated" for updated rows... And i got error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'Updated'.
```

After a while of google, i found out some more post that said only 2 logical tables available are: Inserted and Deleted...

I'm confused... What should i use since my Trigger rely on the Updated table that contain the updated row, and use it to insert to another table or the same table with new PK...

Thank you very much

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two dummy tables are called **`Inserted`** (available in `INSERT` and `UPDATE` triggers) and **`Deleted`** (available in `DELETE` and `UPDATE` triggers).

There is no `Updated` dummy table in SQL Server triggers.

For an `FOR UPDATE` trigger, the `Deleted` table contains the old values, while the `Inserted` table contains the new ones.

Marc